# Unicode versions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, unicode

The documentation of [CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory.aspx) says:

> Note that [*CharUnicodeInfo*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory.aspx) does not always return the same [UnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx) value as the [*Char*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) method when passed a particular character as a parameter.
>
> The [*CharUnicodeInfo*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory.aspx) method is **designed to reflect the current version of the Unicode standard**. In contrast, although the [*Char*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) method usually reflects the current version of the Unicode standard, it might return a character's category based on a previous version of the standard, or it might return a category that differs from the current standard to preserve backward compatibility.

So, which version of the Unicode standard is reflected by [*CharUnicodeInfo*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory.aspx) and [*Char*.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) in which version of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the [String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) states the Unicode version that the .NET Framework 4 and 4.5 conform to:

[**.NET Framework 4**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> In the .NET Framework 4, sorting, casing, normalization, and Unicode character information is synchronized with Windows 7 and conforms to the Unicode 5.1 standard.

[**.NET Framework 4.5**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In the .NET Framework 4.5 running on the Windows 8 operating system, sorting, casing, normalization, and Unicode character information conforms to the Unicode 6.0 standard. On other operating systems, it conforms to the Unicode 5.0 standard.

Comment: I'm still interested in the Unicode standards that previous versions of the .NET Framework conform to.

Comment: .net 3.5 - Unicode 5.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: .net 1.1 - Unicode 3.1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Tom: The same page claims Unicode 5.0 for .NET 4.5. This is obviously only half true. The text seems just to apply to the list of Unicode character categories (which probably does not change very often between Unicode versions), not to the Unicode version used by Windows/the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote some tests to confirm that .net 3.5 doesn't indeed support Unicode 5.0 on Windows 7. I've also tested to conform that .net 4.0 on Windows 7 supports 5.1 but not 5.2. By support I mean that the CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory returns the expected value for the specific Unicode version.

Comment: @dtb, I think you are not answering your own question completely. The documentation you quoted is incorrect (as of .NET 4.5.2 running on Windows 8.1). GetUnicodeCategory does not comply with Unicode 6 categorization. Try this character for example: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f389/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the unicode version isn't stored. The character lookup is implemented by storing the character info in an embedded resource called "charinfo.nlp" in mscorlib.dll, and this is used as a lookup table internally. There is a "version" property on the header to this lookup table data, but it is "0" in the binary data (offset 0x20), so I'm not sure what that's a version of, or if it's just not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

As [Michael Kaplan states](http://www.siao2.com/2005/12/23/506887.aspx):

> The version released by The Unicode
>   Consortium.
>
> Because there really is no definitive
>   answer to this very non-specific
>   question. The answer always depends
>   entirely on the [usually one] specific
>   issue that the person asking is
>   looking for the answer to
>
> So the polite answer in the end is IT
>   DEPENDS ON WHAT YOU MEAN. CAN YOU
>   ELABORATE A BIT?

Comment: *"Unicode properties ... depends on product version. Though Whidbey is 4.1 not 3.2 and Vista hasn't shipped yet but the latest CTP is 4.1."* Thanks for that link, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) page has a wiki comment by Shawn Steele from microsoft, which I think should explain why using CharUnicodeInfo is preferred.

Comment: But thats what it leads to. How does the Unicode version matter when it cannot work correctly. Did you try it with an example character (non-English) to find the difference instead?

Comment: For example, the character `'\u0C58'` (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0c58/index.htm) was added in Unicode version 5.1.0 with category *Letter, Other*.

"The `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory` method is designed to reflect the current version of the Unicode standard."

But `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory` returns `UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned`. So it **does not** reflect the current Unicode version 5.1.0. Which version **does** it reflect?

Comment: What do you expect it to return (if it returns OtherNotAssigned)?

Comment: I found this page which says .net framework 1.1/2.0 supports Unicode version 3.1 (link: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETcsharp/Aug2005/post23858463.asp). Pardon my ignorance on this topic.

Comment: The link in the answer of `devio` says Whidbey (i.e. Visual Studio 2005) is *4.1*. VS2005 was released alongside .NET Framework 2.0. So, one of the two (3.1 or 4.1) must be wrong...